# How to enable developer mode on Chromium OS running in VM (virtualbox)

Tags: virtualbox, google-chrome-os

I am trying to test android app on Chrome OS running in VirtualBox based on these [instructions on android developers site.](https://developer.android.com/topic/arc/index.html#testing)

One of steps is to enable Developer mode on Chrome OS. Instructions for some devices can be found [here](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices) but I am not sure how to enable it on Chrome OS in VM.

Chrome OS image is downloaded from this [link](https://neverware.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/214564457-Un-Official-CloudReady-Virtual-Machine-Images-)

Can anybody help? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The [link you've provided](https://neverware.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/214564457-Un-Official-CloudReady-Virtual-Machine-Images-) is not a ChromeOS image (ChromeOS is only available pre-installed on hardware from Google manufacturing partners, eg. Chromebooks), but ChromiumOS-based distribution, provided by the third-party vendor.

At the moment (Q4'2017), it is possible to run Android Apps only on ChromeOS (not ChromiumOS), and only on the specific [hardware](https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chrome-os-systems-supporting-android-apps).